# Units of Neuron input current

Tags: units, biophysics

My question stems from some of the equations used in a paper in Phys Rev E titled "Dynamical response of the Hodgkin-Huxley model in the high-input regime" (located here: http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.73.041902). The part of interest can be found in pages 2-3. I'm trying to compare some results I've gotten to results they've gotten.

Basically, you have equations describing a neuron and the neuron receives stochastic input current from other neurons modeled by this equation:

$I(t) = C\Delta V \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_e}\sum_l \delta(t-t_k^l) - \sum_{m=1}^{N_i}\sum_n \delta(t-t_m^n)\right]$

Here, C is the membrane capactiance ($1 \mu F/cm^2$), $\Delta V$ is change in voltage when a spike is transmitted to my neuron $(=0.5 mV)$, $N_e$ and $N_i$ are the number of excitatory (inhibitory) neurons that contribute spikes which increase (decrease) the voltage by $\Delta V$, and the input spikes are modeled by a Poisson process of rate $\nu_0$ (= $100$ Hz).

From equation 7, they say that the since the distribution is Poissonian, the input current has some average stimulation given by:

$$\bar{I} = C\Delta V \nu_0 (N_e-N_i)$$

Usually, input current of a neuron is measured in $\mu A/cm^2$. When the average below $6.27 \mu A/cm^2$, the neuron isn't firing, and when it's above $9.78 \mu A/cm^2$, it's firing repetitively.

However, when I try to use their values:

$$\bar{I} = (1 \frac{\mu F}{cm^2} \times \frac{1A*s/V}{10^6\mu F} \times \frac{10^6 \mu A}{1A}\times 0.5mV \times \frac{1V}{10^3 mV}\times 100Hz \times (N_e-N_i))$$ 
$$= 50,000 \frac{\mu A}{cm^2} \times (N_e-N_i)$$

This seems like an extraordinarily large input current considering they're considering input currents on the order of single and low double-digits, and typically current is looked at in that range. I'm trying to find out if the parameters I've used for my model or in the silent or repetitively firing regime, and so I'm trying to compare with this model, but clearly I'm not getting a reasonable result from their calculation

Comment: Have you tried writing to the authors of the paper?